# codebuild / rails / rspec failure not sending error signal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, rspec, aws-codebuild

Running our rails rspec test suite within aws codebuild; rspec failure are reported but codebuild does not see it as it should (stopping the suite)

What should be done to send the correct signal to codebuild ?

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean? Send error signals were? Do you have any CB logs demonstrating the issue?

Comment: [akritib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14291330) wrote an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66237293) saying "https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/test-report-rspec.html You can use junit formatter to make it compatible with AWS CodeBuild."